# JsonPath Conditions | JMETER

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath, json-path-expression

**Need help**
trying to fetch all the 'id' for the componentConsumerSelectionType that equal 2 and exist under a particular "productId" ("123ecc29f29-bc03-41d7-b107-db3be8103216")

example 1:
"productId": "23451a29f0c3-9180-4cd7-a5c7-282f6689c31a"
"id": "8291365c-df9f-4d7b-8f34-be0b500065ee", *(*because* "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,)*

example 2:
"productId": "123ecc29f29-bc03-41d7-b107-db3be8103216"
"id": "a3d14456-64cb-4cae-b749-133c4b6a476a", *(*because* "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,)*

example 3:
"id": "a3d14456-64cb-4cae-b749-133c4b6a476a",*(*because* "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,)*

example 2:
"id": "3f4b1a61-5d80-4b78-8c20-9f2b92022cf4", **wrong** *(*because* "componentConsumerSelectionType": 1,)*

**I'm using this command to retrieve**
*$..[?(@.productId=="ecc29f29-bc03-41d7-b107-db3be8103216" && @.componentGroups[0].components[0].componentConsumerSelectionType == 2)].componentGroups[*].components[*].id*

**INPUT**

{

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": "2344248b1b3-a7c5-4102-b45e-d0d6a4345329433d",
        "productId": "23451a29f0c3-9180-4cd7-a5c7-282f6689c31a",
        "productName": "100%",
        "pools": [
            {
                "id": "cb720883-04f1-4be4-a416-2f0c75230768",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "355548b5-b032-44f5-bf91-acfe987be3aa",
                        "optionAmount": 1.0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "$1",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/1-dollar-ball.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "ee8e2b49-7539-4ddd-90a4-6745b1385733",
                        "optionAmount": 20.0,
                        "optionIndex": 3,
                        "optionName": "$20",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/20-dollar-ball.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "FUNs",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "2f1403cb-df3e-4fbf-b594-352f76943895",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "a5dc21e7-cc4e-4e93-b74f-1f4b19f322ef",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "Heads",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/OneHundredPercent/LibertyBellCoin.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Heads",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ],
        "componentGroups": [
            {
                "id": "126140ac-1cfa-40a3-9ab7-1a84469ab0db",
                "poolId": "cb720883-04f1-4be4-a416-2f0c75230768",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "8291365c-df9f-4d7b-8f34-be0b500065ee",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,
                        "componentName": "FUN",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "FUN Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "03ed0e60-8fba-4e01-83c2-ce960bf5e889",
                "poolId": "2f1403cb-df3e-4fbf-b594-352f76943895",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "3f4b1a61-5d80-4b78-8c20-9f2b92022cf4",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 1,
                        "componentName": "Heads",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Heads Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "b0793365-7212-44db-a044-12c213c020c2",
        "productId": "123ecc29f29-bc03-41d7-b107-db3be8103216",
        "productName": "FUN Powerball",
        "pools": [
            {
                "id": "d929dd55-b0a8-4092-acff-570c638764f1",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "66ff00ab-0aba-479a-b96d-9f6011531440",
                        "optionAmount": 2.0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "$2",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/2-dollar-ball.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "9e6b0868-19b3-466d-bed2-7055efc1e993",
                        "optionAmount": 3.0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "$2 + Power Play",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/2-dollar-ball+megaplier.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "FUNs",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "e63f9eea-4966-4c83-8764-28f8ba19f551",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "7cf2d659-2989-48f9-84f2-1dc117b52f7c",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "1",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/01.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0f0fd71a-3482-4ca5-ba97-e0e1df2993db",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 64,
                        "optionName": "65",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/65.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "916d4cba-b67e-4bfb-bf3e-08bff5e41e2f",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 65,
                        "optionName": "66",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/66.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "7bf74431-bf68-4314-8e8d-2b28ca25706a",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 68,
                        "optionName": "69",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/69.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "White Balls",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "a93aa286-3e9e-47c6-a989-4cbd9b83d529",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "87550358-6a12-4184-9bbd-cd0aed629432",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "1",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/01r.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "fb049500-f6bd-4798-b330-d46b837b974d",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 23,
                        "optionName": "24",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/24r.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "d721c27c-b44a-4ba6-9164-9b7971d92db8",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 24,
                        "optionName": "25",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/25r.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "6a2ff192-7044-4991-91d1-38bbdd6c76a3",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 25,
                        "optionName": "26",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/26r.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Powerballs",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "458199ef-e868-4639-b594-92c0d39422ea",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "d87d6298-85df-4c34-a2aa-b45de2d2d029",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 2,
                        "optionName": "x4",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/multiplier-x4.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "f9c1842c-749e-4a4d-8d4f-55e3ce200fca",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 3,
                        "optionName": "x5",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/multiplier-x5.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "57599727-d2f1-4249-b80f-0c4994244423",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 4,
                        "optionName": "x10",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/multiplier-x10.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Power Plays",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ],
        "componentGroups": [
            {
                "id": "b996b598-57e5-47f4-82a8-a1a54c70a6a9",
                "poolId": "d929dd55-b0a8-4092-acff-570c638764f1",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "db7ae266-bf79-4d63-984a-aea1aa7af460",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,
                        "componentName": "FUN",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "FUN Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "be80677c-114b-4200-a625-badd301373a6",
                "poolId": "e63f9eea-4966-4c83-8764-28f8ba19f551",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "8b750179-6ead-425e-b5a2-ab422e72a03e",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "White Ball - 1",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3a87a9aa-d8c8-465a-ae35-f7d894204b13",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "White Ball - 2",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "6b674bc4-1143-4558-8020-88872064b6d2",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "White Ball - 3",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0cf02fdf-c717-4ea0-a230-cb837792e7f5",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "White Ball - 4",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "e627485b-eb3b-4afe-a20d-bed5c30ba195",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "White Ball - 5",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "White Ball Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "00757a5a-a544-4f4f-985b-60d516a999b6",
                "poolId": "a93aa286-3e9e-47c6-a989-4cbd9b83d529",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "e4c6e609-954a-4707-88b5-c47993fb3f82",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "Powerball",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Powerball Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "eb50e66d-fb77-4d7c-845a-b9492a4c29d1",
                "poolId": "458199ef-e868-4639-b594-92c0d39422ea",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "21a81d68-d9c1-4bea-ad7f-5656584fb37c",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 1,
                        "componentName": "Power Play",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Power Play Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a7bb18a0-9231-4e04-8542-4a86fe4f7f25",
        "productId": "557a97a5-ef93-46b7-868c-4f26439fbcb9",
        "productName": "FUN Pick 3",
        "pools": [
            {
                "id": "efc2ab5c-c709-4b1d-81a7-e61a8d120d8d",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "cf85f8ca-7686-4585-b154-2e069e7bf976",
                        "optionAmount": 0.50,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "$.50",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/01.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "b0f6c744-af0a-4395-a2d5-bfaf39aeeab5",
                        "optionAmount": 1.0,
                        "optionIndex": 1,
                        "optionName": "$1",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/01.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "FUNs",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "60b8910b-baa7-4776-bb7a-05f277887a11",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "5960a4af-0b74-4c2b-b8a4-2dc4033e96a2",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 4,
                        "optionName": "Split Pair",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilesplitpair.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "c2a817ca-1bd8-4b5b-8f6f-e12f3286ea54",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 5,
                        "optionName": "Back Pair",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilebackpair.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Play Types",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "53fb7c9a-17dd-4f95-94b0-0110433404a2",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "id": "fae5912c-9d4a-466b-b515-d60b3186c2e5",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 0,
                        "optionName": "0",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen00.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "42055e6a-f08a-48b4-a7c8-41b87f11ca51",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 1,
                        "optionName": "1",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen01.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "ea28a99c-6068-4d67-8e2d-c6857656b499",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 2,
                        "optionName": "2",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen02.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "bf5e29ea-a377-46ad-865d-e4585d652b13",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 3,
                        "optionName": "3",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen03.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "41c26a4b-ce86-4c28-ae5a-35c13a539fbc",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 4,
                        "optionName": "4",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen04.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "fcb34895-25b9-4e5e-8a00-652febfcd31e",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 5,
                        "optionName": "5",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen05.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "0f0cf6ef-a7b7-4d11-98c4-0ea2cfd32f39",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 6,
                        "optionName": "6",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen06.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3db2fafd-698c-44bb-a4be-f9e43ee6248b",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 7,
                        "optionName": "7",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen07.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "25d17003-9db8-407b-b6e2-65c0c2f014a0",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 8,
                        "optionName": "8",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen08.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "37232037-ca87-4f2e-99a4-40cbfec2bf62",
                        "optionAmount": 0.0,
                        "optionIndex": 9,
                        "optionName": "9",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": "https://123/media/tilegreen09.png"
                    }
                ],
                "poolName": "Numbers",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ],
        "componentGroups": [
            {
                "id": "85ee94f1-fbcf-4392-aa08-5320abc13dcc",
                "poolId": "efc2ab5c-c709-4b1d-81a7-e61a8d120d8d",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "a3d14456-64cb-4cae-b749-133c4b6a476a",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,
                        "componentName": "FUN",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "FUN Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "2be68fe5-2872-4631-b994-bb8e691db233",
                "poolId": "60b8910b-baa7-4776-bb7a-05f277887a11",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "d50aeef2-4821-4247-b712-585a2ba55f81",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 2,
                        "componentName": "Play Type",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Play Type Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "9b3433e8-48f3-4b37-bccb-e0ed5c55ffe8",
                "poolId": "53fb7c9a-17dd-4f95-94b0-0110433404a2",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "ed6a4930-2558-414d-b47f-a3f95e719f60",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "Front Number",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Front Number Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "6ca0c5d1-0939-4603-9c0f-d6be5171a068",
                "poolId": "53fb7c9a-17dd-4f95-94b0-0110433404a2",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "e0957685-22d8-4827-a3db-a1e2e0b5b76b",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "Middle Number",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Middle Number Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": "e2ed942b-98e2-4d91-a500-ab5884acf66f",
                "poolId": "53fb7c9a-17dd-4f95-94b0-0110433404a2",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "id": "98b3c77a-bb25-4a45-a2ca-c90a79c75ecb",
                        "componentConsumerSelectionType": 0,
                        "componentName": "Back Number",
                        "audio": null,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "componentGroupName": "Back Number Components",
                "audio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly getting your requirement the only `id` which matches your criteria would be `db7ae266-bf79-4d63-984a-aea1aa7af460` and it can be fetched using the following [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression:

```
$.data[?(@.productId == '123ecc29f29-bc03-41d7-b107-db3be8103216')].componentGroups.*.components[?(@.componentConsumerSelectionType == 2)].id
```

Demo (assumes JsonPath Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener):

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you so much, Dmitri! Very impressive idea!
I'm getting more conditions on the data from different arrays and was wondering if you could share a good article showing different syntax/ideas on this topic